# Can pylint3 be used to check only a patch/diff?

Tags: python-3.x, pylint

Both pep8 and pylint3 can be used to check whole files, for example:

```
pep8 /home/me/myfile.py
pylint3 /path/to/file.py
```

In addition, pep8 allows checking only a unified diff, as per the manual:

> --diff report only lines changed according to the unified diff received on STDIN

So that we can do something like the following example, to run pep8 on my last commit only:

```
git log -p -1 /path/to/file.py | pep8 --diff
```

Is there a similar option for pylint3, so that existing code can (mostly) be ignored? Looking at the man page, I couldn't find one, but wondering if I could be missing a trick...

By the way, I said "mostly" because I noticed that `pep8` also checks the surrounding lines present in the unified diff, which seems like a bug.